# Can I check milliseconds in facebook comments via devtool in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, facebook, datetime, frontend, google-chrome-devtools

We are playing via facebook a Football World Cup game with friends.
Point is to type who will score goals current day. The rule for the booking is that who is faster wins and can book player for himself.

[Example of booking comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM1kJ.png)

Is there any option to check what is the time with miliseconds details after we post comments in the same time? Only thing is that facebook puts these comments with unknown order. I guess that the order is correct (because it's just requests queue as I suspect) but it would be happy to check if there is an option to check via devtool f.ex. in Chrome what was the time.

I was studing devtool but I could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

I dug around in facebook responses and there are a few requests to `graphql/`:
[image: graphql requests]

One of them has comments data. In that particular response accessing

```
data.feedback.display_comments.edges[0].node.created_time
```

shows

```
1669209480
```

which is a timestamp of creation

This type of a timestamp is epoch time in seconds.

**It doesn't include milliseconds information**